# Vulkan cannot find physical devices on windows 10

Tags: windows, graphics, driver, nvidia, vulkan

I am very new to the vulkan API and have been having problems with getting it working. When I run the vulkan SDK examples or attempt to run my own code, vulkan is unable to find any supported devices. I have attempted to completely reinstall my display drivers, a complete reinstall of the vulkan SDK, a manual install of the vulkan runtime and tried installing the beta version of the nvidia vulkan drivers. I am running an `Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 Ti` which should support vulkan just fine. The driver version is 451.79 and the vulkan SDK version is 1.2.148.0.

When it comes to using my own code, I am able to succesfully create an instance and setup debug callbacks. The error comes in as soon as I attempt to use `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices`. The callback prints out this error:

```
    Vulkan Callback: [Loader Message] code: 0 : setupLoaderTrampPhysDevs:  Failed during dispatch call of 'vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices' to lower layers or loader to get count.
```

Along with that error I immediately check if the device count is 0, which ends up being true.

I feel like I have a problem with my vulkan RT or vulkan SDK install but I can't figure out what it is. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I have also tried running `vulkaninfo` and that does successfully find my GPU and lists information about it.

Comment: What is the `VkResult`? Uninstall all the stuff. You do not need RT and SDK to test this. RT is installed by the driver anyway. SDK is only for development. Make sure to reinstall and update **all** the drivers (such as integrated Intel or AMD too if there are some in the Device Manager). Test using the `vulkaninfo` app installed with the driver to discount any error in your code.

Comment: @krOoze Oh that just reminded me, vulkaninfo does work and succesfully finds my GPU to list information about it. I'll edit the original post to reflect that.
I have also reinstalled all display drivers though that doesn't seem to have changed anything. The `VkResult` from `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` is weirdly `VK_SUCCESS` despite the error coming from the validation layer (and failure to find the GPU).

Comment: In that case show yer MVCE